# Galois cover and solvability

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

This is a very general question: let $f:X\to \mathbb P^1$ be a branched cover of compact Riemann surfaces, where $X\subset \mathbb P^n\times \mathbb P^1$ and $f$ is the natural projection. For any reguler $y\in \mathbb P^1$, the fiber $f^{-1}(y)$ contains $d$ points. We call the $f$ is *solvable* if there is a formula for these $d$ points in terms of $y$.

I want to know that, if the following two things are related?

(i) The cover of $f$ is Galois (i.e. normal);

(ii) $f$ is solvable, as defined above.

Comment: What do you mean by "a formula"?

Comment: The fiber contains $d$ points for almost every $y$, for the few remaining points it is $d$ points [counted with multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Hurwitz_formula). When $|f^{-1}(y)|=d$ for every $y$ it is a proper map in which case it must be $d=1$ (because $f^{-1}(y)$ is locally holomorphic $\Bbb{C} \to X$, since $\Bbb{C}$ is simply connected $f^{-1}$ is entire, doing the same with $f^{-1}(1/y)$ means $f^{-1}$ is holomorphic, so $f$ is biholomorphic $\Bbb{P^1} \to X$)

Comment: @Servaes I mean in the sense in Galois theory, solvable by radicals.

Comment: @reuns Yes you are right. I should say for regular $y$. I edited the text.